# How can I accept zeros in phone numbers using jQuery, but prevent them from being the first digit entered?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#mobileid").keypress(function(event) {
    //$("#mobileid").attr('maxlength','11');
  // Backspace, tab, enter, end, home, left, right
  // We don't support the del key in Opera because del == . == 46.
  var controlKeys = [8, 9, 13, 35, 36, 37, 39];
  // IE doesn't support indexOf
  var isControlKey = controlKeys.join(",").match(new RegExp(event.which));
  // Some browsers just don't raise events for control keys. Easy.
  // e.g. Safari backspace.
  if (!event.which || // Control keys in most browsers. e.g. Firefox tab is 0
      (49 <= event.which && event.which <= 57) || // Always 1 through 9
      (48 == event.which && $(this).attr("value")) || // No 0 first digit
      isControlKey) { // Opera assigns values for control keys.
    return;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

This function is not accepting zeros in the phone number in my text box.

Can you please let me know why this is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You're excluding `0` in `49 <= event.which && event.which <= 57`, which is why you're unable to enter it. First, change this to `48 <= event.which && event.which <= 57` to include it.

Second, you're also trying to exclude `0` from being the first digit. The line `(48 == event.which && $(this).attr("value"))` doesn't actually do that.

Instead, check the first entry using `this.selectionStart == 0`, and ensure **that** is between `49` and `57` (**inclusive** of `0`). For any point other than the start, you want to check for an `event.which` between `48` and `57` (**exclusive** of `0`).

That comes to:

```
((this.selectionStart > 0 && 48 <= event.which && event.which <= 57) || (this.selectionStart == 0 && 49 <= event.which && event.which <= 57))
```

And can be seen working as expected in the following snippet:

```js
$("#mobileid").keypress(function(event) {
  //$("#mobileid").attr('maxlength','11');
  // Backspace, tab, enter, end, home, left, right
  // We don't support the del key in Opera because del == . == 46.
  var controlKeys = [8, 9, 13, 35, 36, 37, 39];
  // IE doesn't support indexOf
  var isControlKey = controlKeys.join(",").match(new RegExp(event.which));
  // Some browsers just don't raise events for control keys. Easy.
  // e.g. Safari backspace.
  if (!event.which || // Control keys in most browsers. e.g. Firefox tab is 0
    ((this.selectionStart > 0 && 48 <= event.which && event.which <= 57) || (this.selectionStart == 0 && 49 <= event.which && event.which <= 57)) || isControlKey) { // Opera assigns values for control keys.
    return;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="mobileid">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to not allow a 0 as the first character entered into the input. If this is the case, then the code you want is this:

```
$("#mobileid").keypress(function(event) {
  //$("#mobileid").attr('maxlength','11');
  // Backspace, tab, enter, end, home, left, right
  // We don't support the del key in Opera because del == . == 46.
  var controlKeys = [8, 9, 13, 35, 36, 37, 39];
  // IE doesn't support indexOf
  var isControlKey = controlKeys.join(",").match(new RegExp(event.which));
  // Some browsers just don't raise events for control keys. Easy.
  // e.g. Safari backspace.
 if (!event.which || // Control keys in most browsers. e.g. Firefox tab is 0
   (49 <= event.which && event.which <= 57) || // Always 1 through 9
   ((48 == event.which) && ($(this).val() !== '')) || // No 0 first digit
   isControlKey) { // Opera assigns values for control keys.
     return;
   } else {
     event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

I've used changed this line:
`(48 == event.which && $(this).attr("value"))` to `((48 == event.which) && ($(this).val() !== '')) ||`.

This checks that the key matches 0 (where the 48 and event.which come into it) and that the input is not equal to an empty string (where the $(this).val() comes into it). $(this).val() is an easier short-hand than $(this).attr("value").

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/XaJrxp).